# Combine Multiple GetMappings into a Single Endpoint and Filter

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest

Right now I have several permutations of `GET requests` in my API and I realize that this isn't scalable as these are hardcoded and aren't flexible. I would like to have a single endpoint: Ie: `/api/customer` that can filter with all parameters optional, so if I wanted to filter all of my theoretical customers named Bob who are 50 I can without creating an endpoint that is literally `/api/customer/{name}/{age}` and hardcoding that.

I have found a lot of information concerning all manner of things when looking for an answer on SO and various blogs but being new to Java, REST, and Spring/Spring boot I am having a difficult time separating out the wheat from the chaff to get a straight answer. I'd love to get pointed in the right direction.

Comment: The standard way to do this in an HTTP API is with query parameters. You might find either a `Map` parameter or Querydsl useful.

Comment: If the number of parameters are more, then you can go with `POST` request, and can have `FilterDTO` as request body, containing all the parameters which need be filtered out. Sending many parameters in Query will be a messy solution.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- how do you go about adding the service layer with the `Map` parameters without adding infinitely scaling `if statements`? I might be missing something.

Comment: It depends _very_ much on the specifics of your persistence system. I suggest looking into Querydsl, particularly the Spring MVC and Spring Data support for it.